# adding escape sequence to Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Tags: c#, escaping

The path that is returned from Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() contains non escaped '\' characters. How do i escape them ?

Comment: The way you would escape any C# string, do you know how to do that?

Comment: Oh could you please tell me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a replace:

```
string escapedPath = unescapedPath.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```